# Maven install java 6 project

Tags: java, maven, java-6

I have a maven 3.8.4 and java 17 jdk. But I need to install old project where are source and target set to 6 version, because one of my projects uses it as dependency. How can I do that correctly, so later I will be able to use it as dependency in a newer project with source and target >6? My OS is Ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: First migrate that old project to newer JDK versions..... JDK17 does only support building for java.7 minimum...(via --release)..

Answer (score 1):

I’ve just gone through that exercise on an old repository,  including having GitHub Actions compile it. See https://github.com/ravn/jscheme-1998 - note that I decided that it was more important to keep the Java 6 comparability for this particular project than to switch to Java 8 as required by the latest version of slf4j.

Java 17 can read Java 6 byte code, so you may be able to use what you have in jar form already.

If you need to compile and reinstall, Java 8 and 11 can target Java 6 so use that instead of Java 17 for that project.

Easiest way is probably to download an OpenJDK build in zip form, unpack it and prepend the `bin` folder to your path and unset JAVA_HOME.

That said, upgrading the project to compile with at least Java 8, preferably Java 17 is a good idea. You most likely use libraries that has been found security vulnerabilities in.

Comment: OP: if you did actually run that application on a Java 6 platform, the platform itself would most likely have multiple unpatched security issues.   Public (i.e. not paid for) releases of Java 6 have not gotten security fixes in over 9 years.